# Add Video in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

In my ASP.NET Aplication, i had this DB Model:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozi2d.png)

I want add a Video, so i had this controller action:

```html
public ActionResult AddVideo(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
        {

            if (file != null)
            {
                SoftIdeiaEntities1 db = new SoftIdeiaEntities1();
                string VideoName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Video/" + VideoName);


                // save image in folder
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                //save new record in database
                Video record = new Video();
                record.VideoName = VideoName;
                record.ContentID = id;


                db.Video.Add(record);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //Display records
            return View();
        }
```

And my view is that:

```html
@model SoftIdeiaFinalProject.Models.DB.Video

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddVideo";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddVideo</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        Video<br />
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details", Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values)
</div>
```

I cant save an image in db and folder. What can i do to resolve that issue?

Comment: You say "I can't save an image"... why not?  Does it give an error (if so, what) does it just "do nothing", does it do something, but not what you expect?

Comment: It doesn't work, but don't give me any error @EricBurdo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can import picture from Web?

https://forums.asp.net/t/2104234.aspx?Convert+HTML+string+URL+to+Image+using+asp+net+C+

Comment: No, i want upload local videos